# Answers with large images are cut off on Firefox for Android

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, firefox

As seen on [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) only answers with large images are cutoff.

[image]

The first answer is fine despite having an image:

[image]

Another example can be found at [How do I install the Firefox Developer Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition)

[image]

I've tested it on Chrome and it is fine. I'm running Firefox 35 on Android 4.4.4.

Comment: I've got the same problem quite frequently, often with posts that contain code blocks. Interestingly, it works for *most* of such posts if I rotate the phone to landscape orientation, but portrait orientation is broken quite often.